# How could I tell from the reported tour weight whether a Hamilton circuit of G has been found?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Here is the idea of using a travelling salesman algorithm
to search for a Hamilton circuit in any simple graph.

Consider this graph $G$:

[image]

TSP algorithms usually
work on a complete
weighted graph. One way
to transform G into such
a graph $G^*$
is:
[image]

Suppose the Nearest Neighbour algorithm were applied to $G^*$
. **How could I tell
from the reported tour weight whether a Hamilton circuit of $G$ had been found?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the edges of the original graph $G$ will have weight 1 in the new graph $G^*$. All the other edges in $G^*$ have higher weights.

Suppose the Nearest Neighbour algorithm had found a valid Hamiltonian tour, that is to say, all the edges it chose are edges of the original graph. How many edges are in that tour? So what is its total weight?

Suppose the Nearest Neighbour algorithm had found an invalid Hamiltonian tour, that is to say, the Hamiltonian tour of $G^*$ it found uses some edges that are not edges of the original graph. What can you say about its total weight?

Comment: The total weight will be 10, I think. But how does that answer my question?

Comment: @PropositionX So if it finds a valid Hamiltonian tour, it reports a tour weight of 10. Will it also report a tour weight of 10 if it found an invalid Hamiltonian tour?

Comment: No I guess. So the answer is just I need to look at whether the weight is 10. Right？

Comment: Yes, Actually, 10 is the weight of a Hamiltonian Cycle, i.e. a closed tour, a tour that ends back in the starting vertex. If the algorithm was set up to find open tours, the reported weight would be 9.